# Mathematica 12.1.1 does not boot up but kernel does

Tags: kernel-startup

While Mathematica's kernel loads quite well, whenever I try to boot up the program itself it simply never boots. I've tried completely erasing Mathematica and reinstalling, but this did not work. What is going on, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Contact Wolfram tech support.

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you go to your `$UserBaseDirectory`(see @cvgmt's answer), and rename the file in the  `FrontEnd` directory named `init.m`, does it start again? (I'm asking because I had this exact thing happen to me yesterday, and that was the fix for me)

Comment: @LukasLang there are no files in that directory for me.

Answer (score 3):

Since Mathematica's kernel work, so you can use

```
$UserBaseDirectory

(* may be  C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica”  in Windows
 and “/home/YourUserName/.Mathematica” in Linux *)
```

to get the path of your local settings directory and clean up all the files.